# Can't change folder in Python3 in Linux mint

Tags: python, linux

I have several python scripts that run perfectly on windows, and I use os.chdir(path) to change my desired location.

I assume it's some silly catch that I can't find but, I constantly get the same error in linux mint terminal:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/Development/myapplication-cpp-2.1/examples/'
```

I'm calling: `os.chdir("~/Development/myapplication-cpp-2.1/examples/")`

If I do `cd ~/Development/myapplication-cpp-2.1/examples/` from terminal it works perfectly fine.

I then printed `os.getcwd()` which resulted with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: Thanks all, yes, expanding path works... I did not think about it at all. I knew it was a silly catch.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `os.path.expanduser()` [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to expand a path with the `~` shorthand. `chdir` doesn't understand such relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand the path first

```
os.path.expanduser("~/Development/myapplication-cpp-2.1/examples/")
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser

Answer (score 0):

The point is that your shell substitutes `~` by your home directory, which python doesn't.

`~` is something shell-specific and not filesystem-wide.